# JQuery Form CSS Visibility

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I have a form that is hidden on page load by using CSS attribute visibility:hidden

I want it to change to visible when the only button on my page is clicked.  I have tried numerous things such as using display attribute instead, .show(), etc.

However, nothing I try makes the form appear.

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btnClick').click(function () {
        $(".Border").css('visibility', 'visible');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" class="btnClick" id="btnClick" onclick="DisplayForm()"value = "Click for Receipt"/>

<form class="Border" id="myform" action="" method="get">
Enter something in the box: <br />
<input type="text" name="one" value=""/>
<br />
<input type="text" name="two" value="" />
<br />
<input type="text" name="three" value="" />
</form>
```

CSS

```
.Border
{
    visibility:hidden;
}

.btnClick
{
}
```

Comment: What does the `DisplayForm()` function do?

Comment: Could you try to code $("#myform") instead of $(".Border"). Of to wrap from into some div with id or class and do the same.

Comment: is it possible that DisplayForm() is calling preventDefault?

Comment: Not sure if the use of uppercases to declare classes and ids are permitted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get firebug for your browser in order to get a log of your javascript errors, as this might halt your script.

If there is no error logged, add alert calls in every step of your script to check if there's an impass:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
alert("1");
    $('.btnClick').click(function () {
alert("2");
        $(".Border").css('visibility', 'visible');
alert("complete");
    });
});
```

Following the count, you'll be able to know what line of code isn't firing propertly. Let us know we'll be able to help you out further.

I would also remove your onClick call to DisplayForm() from your button element as it seems that its intended use might be conflicting with your posted script.

Comment: I have removed the DisplayForm() and I have added the alerts.  Each alert displays.  1 on page load and the other two on button click, however nothing displays

Comment: Ok, this means that the script is catching the click. Let's check your css call in your jquery. First let's check your selector. I'm not sure if uppercases are allowed in class and id declarations, but maybe jquery is messing up here. Try setting the Border class to border.

Comment: Not sure what was incorrect.  I had changed many things to match others' suggestions.  I put the code back with this syntax and its working.  Final code$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("1");
    $('.btnClick').click(function () {
        alert("2");
        $(".Border").css('visibility', 'visible');
        alert("complete");
    });
});

Comment: I'd probably attribute it to some back syntax somewhere. It's sure that having multiple functions called on click (such as DisplayForm) can cause issues if one function limits the scope of the event to itself. Aswell, scripting is very sensitive to the syntax, especially with selections in Jquery. Glad it works though!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AWjCw/

Perhaps there is a conflict with your jQuery `$(document).ready`?

Comment: I removed it and it still doesnt work.  Outstanding tool though!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery you can use functions like `show()` and `fadeIn()`. See below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btnClick').click(function () {
        $("#myForm").show(); // or use .fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Then I do this with my css:

```
#myForm{ display: none; }
```

Not sure why your code isn't working though. I just simplified it ;).

You might try removing `onclick="DisplayForm()"`. This could be causing an error if it's not defined somewhere else?

Comment: I have made all these changes and still nothing.  I removed the DisplayForm() because as everyone has noted Im not using it any longer

Answer (score 0):

In case you're loading this part of the html after the page load through some AJAX call, try this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btnClick').live('click', function () {
        $(".Border").css('visibility', 'visible');
    });
});
```